# Have to twice click on button Javascript - Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I have little script with Google Maps API - get address from user (start and destination) and script shows me geo coordinates and distance from Google Matrix Service. The problem is: when I click the button to Calculate coordinates and distance I need to click it twice - first to show coordinates and second to show the distance between it. Maybe do u know solution for it?

```js
        var firstCityLocationLtd = "";
  var secondCityLocationLtd = "";
        var distanceKm = "";

        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
          initGeocoder();
        });
   
     function initGeocoder() {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var firstCityLocation = document.getElementById('firstLocation').value;
  var secondCityLocation = document.getElementById('secondLocation').value;  
  
  
        geocoder.geocode({'address': firstCityLocation}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
      firstCityLocationLtd = results[0].geometry.location;
            document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = firstCityLocationLtd;
          } else {
            alert('Error: ' + status);
          }
        });
  
  geocoder.geocode({'address': secondCityLocation}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
      secondCityLocationLtd = results[0].geometry.location;
            document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = secondCityLocationLtd;
          } else {
            alert('Error: ' + status);
          }
        });
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;
        service.getDistanceMatrix({
          origins: [firstCityLocationLtd],
          destinations: [secondCityLocationLtd],
          travelMode: 'DRIVING',
          unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
          avoidHighways: false,
          avoidTolls: false
        }, function callback(response, status) {
          if (status !== 'OK') {
            alert('Error was: ' + status);
          } else {
            var originList = response.originAddresses;
            var destinationList = response.destinationAddresses;
            //var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
            //outputDiv.innerHTML = '';

            for (var i = 0; i < originList.length; i++) {
              var results = response.rows[i].elements;
              geocoder.geocode({'address': originList[i]});
              for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                geocoder.geocode({'address': destinationList[j]});
                distanceKm += results[j].distance.value;    
              }
     
            }
   showRoadDetails(firstCityLocationLtd, secondCityLocationLtd, distanceKm);
          }
        })
  }
  
  function showRoadDetails(start, end, distance){
   document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = start;
   document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = end;
   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = distance/1000;
  
  }
```

```css
body {
height:100%;
}

.jumbotron {
 margin-top:20%;
 background-color: rgba(238,238,238,0.9);
}

.game p.labels {
 margin-bottom:2px;
 font-size:14px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}

.inputForm {
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid main">
  <div class="container">

      <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
      <div class="jumbotron">
   <div class="game">
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>Your road</h3>
        
   <p class="labels">From</p><input id="firstLocation" type="textbox" value="Wrocław, Poland" class="inputForm">
   <p class="labels">To</p><input id="secondLocation" type="textbox" value="Warszawa, Poland" class="inputForm"><br/>
   
  </div>
      </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <input id="submit" type="button" value="Calculate it">
   <div id="result1"></div>
   <div id="result2"></div>
   <div id="output"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
 </div>
 </div>
  <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBU2QyOcVY_qoDykdLzX4ywANyPbXJVfZI&callback=initGeocoder&libraries=geometry">
    </script>
```

Comment: Why are you calling the geocoder inside the callback to the distanceMatrix?  That certainly complicates matters (and the call doesn't have a callback function, so it doesn't do anything useful but use up your quota)

Comment: Distance matrix will also work for address of the user. Is there are any reason why you are using Geocoder to get the coordinates and pass them to distance matrix?

Comment: @geocodezip I saw this solution on Google Maps API site, I didn't know that it's unnecessary. Thanks!

Comment: @Coder I didn't know that too, I'm learning all the time so sorry for my silly questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait the result of the geocoder services before you call the DistanceMatrixService . You can do this with Promises ( take a look on the bellow snippet )

```js
// Code goes here

var firstCityLocationLtd = "";
var secondCityLocationLtd = "";
var distanceKm = "";

document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
  initGeocoder();
});

function initGeocoder() {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var firstCityLocation = document.getElementById('firstLocation').value;
  var secondCityLocation = document.getElementById('secondLocation').value;

  var deferFistLocation = $.Deferred();
  var deferSecondLocation = $.Deferred();
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': firstCityLocation
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      firstCityLocationLtd = results[0].geometry.location;
      document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = firstCityLocationLtd;
      deferFistLocation.resolve();

    } else {
      deferFistLocation.reject();
      alert('Error: ' + status);
    }
  });

  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': secondCityLocation
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      secondCityLocationLtd = results[0].geometry.location;
      document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = secondCityLocationLtd;
      deferSecondLocation.resolve();
    } else {
      deferSecondLocation.reject();
      alert('Error: ' + status);
    }
  });

  $.when(deferFistLocation, deferSecondLocation).done(function() {
      var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;
      service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: [firstCityLocationLtd],
        destinations: [secondCityLocationLtd],
        travelMode: 'DRIVING',
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
      }, function callback(response, status) {
        if (status !== 'OK') {
          alert('Error was: ' + status);
        } else {
          var originList = response.originAddresses;
          var destinationList = response.destinationAddresses;
          //var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
          //outputDiv.innerHTML = '';

          for (var i = 0; i < originList.length; i++) {
            var results = response.rows[i].elements;
            geocoder.geocode({
              'address': originList[i]
            });
            for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
              geocoder.geocode({
                'address': destinationList[j]
              });
              distanceKm += results[j].distance.value;
            }

          }
          showRoadDetails(firstCityLocationLtd, secondCityLocationLtd, distanceKm);
        }
      })
    });
}

function showRoadDetails(start, end, distance) {
  document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = start;
  document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = end;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = distance / 1000;

}
```

```css
body {
height:100%;
}

.jumbotron {
 margin-top:20%;
 background-color: rgba(238,238,238,0.9);
}

.game p.labels {
 margin-bottom:2px;
 font-size:14px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}

.inputForm {
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid main">
  <div class="container">

      <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
      <div class="jumbotron">
   <div class="game">
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>Your road</h3>
        
   <p class="labels">From</p><input id="firstLocation" type="textbox" value="Wrocław, Poland" class="inputForm">
   <p class="labels">To</p><input id="secondLocation" type="textbox" value="Warszawa, Poland" class="inputForm"><br/>
   
  </div>
      </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <input id="submit" type="button" value="Calculate it">
   <div id="result1"></div>
   <div id="result2"></div>
   <div id="output"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
 </div>
 </div>
  <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBU2QyOcVY_qoDykdLzX4ywANyPbXJVfZI&callback=initGeocoder&libraries=geometry">
    </script>
```

Comment: This is solution I was looking for, very useful thing, thanks!

Comment: welcome . You can mark as solved the question -> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work